# On trinomials over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Is it true that the number of irreducible trinomials over F_q of degree at most n grows with n like n? See section 4 of
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03789.pdf
for details, heuristic argument, and numerics.

Comment: The number of all trinomials grows much faster.... You probably mean irreducible ones.

Comment: This sounds like a very difficult question. I agree with your heuristics. But the common results about the distribution of irreducibles (that I'm aware of) don't seem to bite at all at such a sparse family of polynomials. I'm sure the question has been studied. IIRC Lidl & Niederreiter say something about irreducible trinomials. People at MathOverflow may know more.